# Showing the hidden buttons

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a screen which is in portrait mode and it shows me some buttons. If the screen is layout is changed to landscape , as you know the height is smaller and width is longer in landscape mode . So i want to show some extra or hidden buttons while my screen's orientation is changed . How do i do that using c# (Xamarin).I am building an application and i want to implement that function in my app like the calculator when it is portrait some buttons are hidden but when is changes to landscape extra buttons can be seen. Please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different layout file with the same name but placed in `layout-land` folder.
So   let's say the xml is in layout folder with name `layout.xml`.
Add `layout.xml` with whatever layout you want to have in landscape mode and put that in `layout-land` folder. When you'll rotate the screen in landscape mode , Android will automatically fetch your xml which you added in `layout-land` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS if you want to show hidden buttons,

ObjectiveC

```
           btn1.hidden = NO;
```

Swift

```
           btn1.hidden = false
```